# Angular 2 animation with calculated timing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

Using TypeScript and Angular 2.4

I have a component with scrolling text (like marqueee) and I have a parameter that specify scroll speed (pixels per second).

How can I dynamically specify animation length using a method from component?

Assume the following component:

```js
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

const SCROLL_SPEED_DEFAULT = 25;

@Component({
  selector: 'text-scroll',
  template: '<span><ng-content></ng-content></span>',
  animations: [
    trigger('hover', [
      state('idle', style({transformX: '0'})),
      state('scrolled', style({transformX: '-100%'})),
      transition('idle => scrolled', [
        animate(this.getAnimationSpeed())
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class TextScrollComponent {
  @Input('speed') speedTime: number = SCROLL_SPEED_DEFAULT;
  private element: HTMLElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = this.el.nativeElement;
  }

  public getAnimationSpeed(): number {
    let element = this.element;
    let elementWidth = $(element).width();
    let difference = this.el.nativeElement.scrollWidth - elementWidth;

    return (difference / Number(this.speedTime)) * 1000;
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<text-scroll>My very <b>loooong..</b> text</text-scroll>
```

Comment: Currently I can't find the way to do this using `@Component` decorator, but maybe `Renderer.animate` will be suitable

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I can't find the way to do this using @Component decorator, but maybe Renderer.animate will be suitable